# Font rendering with custom font widths using Xamarin.iOS

Tags: c#, ios6, fonts, xamarin.ios

I'm using Xamarin.iOS and need to render text strings that have a custom amount of spacing between each gylph. I am currently building a NSMutableAttributedString in which I am passing my font and paragraphstyple information. I been able to display the text string but I need to be able to set a custom amount of spacing between each gylph. Is there a dictionary element that I can add to allow me to configure this value in iOS? Below is the method I am using to build the attributedstring.

```
public NSMutableAttributedString Build()
{
    // Create a new attributed string from text
    var atts = new NSMutableAttributedString(String);

    var attRange = new NSRange(0, atts.Length);
    var attsDic = new NSMutableDictionary();

    var fontObject = new NSObject(Font.Handle);
    attsDic.Add((NSString)"NSFont", fontObject);

    var alignmentSettings = new CTParagraphStyleSettings()
    {
        Alignment = CTTextAlignment.Left,
    };

    var paragraphStyle = new CTParagraphStyle(alignmentSettings);
    var psObject = new NSObject(paragraphStyle.Handle);

    attsDic.Add((NSString)"NSParagraphStyle", psObject);
    atts.SetAttributes(attsDic, attRange);

    return atts;
}
```

Comment: You should try the version of Xamarin.iOS on the beta channel. I heard they have a strongly typed version of `NSAttributedString`, it might be a lot easier to use--no dictionaries, just C# properties.

Comment: @jonathanpeppers I was able to pass CTStringAttributes as a parameter in the AttributedString constructor. I found that I was able to adjust the kerning to increase width between fonts. It does not appear that AttributedString have typed properties that will directly modify string dictionary values. I checked this in the stable and beta channels.